# SQL Query for data consolidation from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Taking a customer table as example

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE payments (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  customer_id INT(11),
  month INT(2),
  year INT(4),
  amount INT(5),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_cust(customer_id)
  REFERENCES customer(id));
```

The payments table contains information about the month, year and amount of payment by the customer.

I have trouble writing a SELECT query.
The result should contain all months of a particular year for all customers, if the customer hasn't made a payment for a particular month, the payment column should be NULL for that month.

```
SELECT * FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN payments p ON c.id = p.customer_id AND p.year = 2017
```

If I run the above query, I only get rows which have months with payments.

I apologize in advance for any mistakes(I'm new to MySQL and StackOverflow).

EDIT: 
The query should return entries for months where payments don't exist. For example, 
If a customer made payment only in June, the query should return entries for other months too with NULL value as payments.

Comment: Typically, you would handle the logic of missing results (for which we know the payment is 0) in application code, e.g. a simple PHP loop.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201701310703048805128

Answer (score -1):

It is actually the opposite join:

```
   Select * from payments p 
   left join customers c 
       on p.customer_id = c.id
```